# Deploy mex file without dependencies

Tags: matlab, cuda, mex

[I am compiling some `mex` files that contain CUDA code.](https://github.com/CERN/TIGRE/blob/master/MATLAB/Compile.m)

With the right compiler installed, and CUDA installed in the machine, the compilation would always succeed and the code then works fine. *Sometimes* one can also use the same compiled `.mexw64` (in the win64 case) in a different PC without the need of compiling it, as long as that PC has CUDA installed. However, if CUDA is not installed, the execution would fail because it can not find the needed libraries.

Is it possible to compile `mex` files and include any library/dependency on them, so they can, in most cases, just be copypasted into a new PC and execute?

Comment: Does CUDA come with static librarys (I have no experience with it). If so, you can pass the name of the static library to the `mex` command, instead of using the `-l` linker command (which prefers dynamic linking).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Assume its in `C:\CUDA\v9.1\lib\x64\cudart.lib`: do you know how to call the `mex` compiler call to make it work? Adding the path to the mex call seem to make it compile, you know if that will suffice? (I'll try to test it myself later too)

Comment: I'm fairly sure that you can just add `\CUDA\v9.1\lib\x64\cudart.lib` to the `mex` command line, instead of `-lcudart`. But make sure it's an actual static library, not the import library for a DLL. Do you know of `DependencyWalker`? It can help you figure out if you have the run-time dependency or not.